How to solve Controller integer parameter could not solve problem
Language: Java
Framework: Spring Boot, MyBatis, MySQL
I have been trying to add like service to my board service. It succeeded it. However, I'm trying to use userNo and boardNo to establish disable like function. However, in the BoardController, where I coded the increaseLike method, whenever I try to get userNo integer parameter, it says like these
Could not resolve parameter [1] in public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> moum.project.controller.BoardController.increaseLike(int,int) throws java.lang.Exception: Required request parameter 'userNo' for method parameter type int is not present
I was able to make like service with only using boardNo but it keep saying those error message whenever I add userNo. Below is the relative codes.
@PostMapping("/increaseLike")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> increaseLike(@RequestParam("boardNo") int boardNo, @RequestParam("userNo") int userNo) throws Exception {
        boolean isLiked = likesService.toggleLike(boardNo, userNo);
        int likeCount = likesService.countLikesByBoard(boardNo);

        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("likeCount", likeCount);
        response.put("isLiked", isLiked); 
        return response;
    }

<resultMap id="LikeMap" type="moum.project.vo.Likes">
        <id column="board_id" property="boardNo"/>
        <result column="user_id" property="userNo"/>
    </resultMap>

    <insert id="addLike" parameterType="moum.project.vo.Likes">
        INSERT INTO likes (board_id, user_id) VALUES (#{boardNo}, #{userNo})
    </insert>`your text`


@Mapper
public interface LikesDao {
    boolean isLiked(Likes like);
    void addLike(Likes like);
    void deleteLike(Likes like);
    int countLikesByBoard(int boardNo);
}


public interface LikesService {
    void addLike(Likes like) throws Exception;
    boolean isLikedByUser(int boardNo, int userNo) throws Exception;
    int countLikesByBoard(int boardNo) throws Exception;
    void deleteLike(Likes like) throws Exception;
    boolean toggleLike(int boardNo, int userNo) throws Exception;
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DefaultLikesService implements LikesService {

    private final LikesDao likesDao;

    @Override
    public void addLike(Likes like) throws Exception {
        likesDao.addLike(like); // 좋아요 추가
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isLikedByUser(int boardNo, int userNo) throws Exception {
        Likes like = new Likes(boardNo, userNo);
        return likesDao.isLiked(like);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean toggleLike(int boardNo, int userNo) throws Exception {
        Likes like = new Likes(boardNo, userNo);
        boolean isLiked = likesDao.isLiked(like);

        if (isLiked) {
            likesDao.deleteLike(like);
        } else {
            likesDao.addLike(like);
        }
        return !isLiked;
    }

    @Override
    public int countLikesByBoard(int boardNo) throws Exception {
        return likesDao.countLikesByBoard(boardNo);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteLike(Likes like) throws Exception {
        likesDao.deleteLike(like);
    }
}

I tried to get rid of userNo then I cannot create function for disabling the like button. Right now only liking is possible not disabling it.

can u show the Http request you are sending ? looks like you are missing userNo in request

the problem is the coming request is missing a parameter int userNo. I see that you use user_id, user_no, this maybe conflict in some how, try to recheck this. Hope thiswill help

Make user you are passing the parameter with the correct name (userNo) while calling controller.
